# Каким образом у codesys получается задать четкую частоту для gpio?

Tags: linux, c, arm, gpio

Каким образом у codesys получается задать четкую частоту для gpio, то есть создаю переменную, она привязана к gpio, делаю цикл с периодом 0.5мс, осцил 1000Гц ровно выдает (изредка 995-1005 так проскакивает).

Если я сделаю то же самое, по логике, через gpiod библиотеку в цикле, как пример:

```
for (;;) {
    gpiod_line_set_value(line, val);
    val = !val;
    usleep(500);
}
```

То частоту выдаст точно не 1000, в районе 850 +- 20. Я безусловно понимаю что это всё дело в вызовах и прочих деталях на таком мелком интервале времени всё это скажется, но разве codesys не то же самое делать должен.

Собственно основной вопрос: как реализовать четкие 1000Гц условных?

Есть предположение, что ассемблера язык там (как отдельные вставки), но хотелось бы поинтересоваться у знающих людей, у кого был опыт с этим делом даже может, что именно можно почитать по этому поводу и в чем дело если кратко.

UPD: CODESYS точно использует тот же gpiod от linux, т.к. номера пинов в ide codesys устанавливаются согласно gpioinfo (line number) + /sys/class/gpio/gpiochipN. Но как он делает это чётко и быстро - неясно.

Comment: @AlexF, у codesys процесса обычный root uid и nice 0 (вывод top показывает). Думаете там драйвер какой-то личный появился внешний для ядра от codesys процесса? Или о чем вы. Всё процессы в юезр моде, ну а gpio переключение и в моем случае тоже до кернела доползет.

Comment: @AlexF, и все же сомнительно, что у него драйвер свой (я просто не знаю как еще в kernel mode код свой выполнять в среде linux) . В /usr/lib/modules ни одного нового файла, в lsmod тоже ничего.

Comment: Стандартный драйвер умеет больше чем просто дрыгать светодиодом.

Comment: Что за проц то?

Comment: @eri, спасибо за ответ. amlogic s905x3, не знаю что вам это даст конечно, дело в linux интерфейсах :)

Comment: ну хотяб можно в его сдк поковыряться

Answer (score 1):

В вашем варианте не учтено время выполнения функции.

Зависит от платы и конкретных пинов, но на многих arm есть хардварные pwm. На малине включается через dtoverlay=pwm,pin=12,func=4 включается и доступен этот шим прямо в sysfs. Пропуски бывают, но очень редко. Скорости сотни килогерц.

Второй вариант - использовать таймер на прерывании. Там можно получить десятки килогерц. И довольно точные результаты при использовании DMA. Но это уже на уровне ядра.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Codesys не создаёт их для работы, он не может в конфигурацию сам залезть, включить и перезагрузить плату. Если только какие-то специальные настройки GPIO есть у линукс интерфейса gpiod (для пользовательского уровня разумеется).

Comment: перезагрузиться надо чтоб в sysfs появились в малине, на других процах может быть не нужно перезагружаться

Comment: благодарю за ответ. Дак у меня и малина есть 4 B, там такая же история, без перезагрузок, только codesys поставил, запустил 0.5мсек цикл он/офф в codesys и все стабильно 1кГц :)

Comment: я на 40кГц шимил чтоб на микрофон не гвлияло) там уже без dtoverlay=pwm не обойтись.

1кГц скорее всего на таймере

Comment: спасибо :) А что за таймер, принцип действия в двух словах, alarm сишный тут рядом или нет ?:)

Comment: Попробуй alarm.

Comment: А попробуй strace сделать той программе. Какие системные вызовы она гонит?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149217/discussion-between-nx4n-and-eri).